# MS office word component runs only if the server is logged on with the same identity

Tags: automation, ms-word, dcom

I have a webservices running on a server, which converts word document into pdf using word automation.

I have given a windows network user account in the identity tab on the MS Office word component using the DCOMCNFG.exe.

I am getting below mentioned error
Exception Message: The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))

But, if I Remote Desktop into that server using the account mentioned in the components identity tab, then it works fine. If I logoff from that server then its giving the above error.

Anyone got any idea!!

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by creating a new pool and setting an identity for the pool.

http://ibrahimuludag.blogspot.com/2011/06/word-automation.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Word automation from a web context you can apply impersonation to execute Word methods with a predefined user identity. In that case you will not need DCOM configuration since Word will already be running in your desired user context.

For a programmatic way of impersonating check out http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/1572.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same issue and pulling my hair out.  It appears to have something to do with allowing the application to be opened from that ASP.Net C# application in IIS.

Did you come up with a solution for this.
I currently have Powerpoint,Excel and Project working and don't remember if I ran into this before as interop assemblies have been very labor intensive to get working.

Mike